# How to efficiently sort two arrays based on the values in one of them?

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

If I have two arrays:

```
a = [  1,   4,   3,   2]
b = ['z', 'w', 'x', 'y']
```

and I want to sort both `a` and `b` based on the values from `a`, i.e.:

```
[  1,  2,  3,  4]      # a 
['z','y','x','w']      # b
```

What is an efficient/idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two distinct vectors I do not know if this is possible.

I would use [sortperm](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.sortperm) that returns a permutation vector `p` that puts `a[p]` in sorted order

```
julia> p=sortperm(a)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
 3
 2

julia> a[p]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> b[p]
4-element Vector{Char}:
 'z': ASCII/Unicode U+007A (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'y': ASCII/Unicode U+0079 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'x': ASCII/Unicode U+0078 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'w': ASCII/Unicode U+0077 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

If performance is important you can also use `sortperm!` that allows using a preallocated permutation vector `p`.

---

**Note:** if you have a matrix you can use [sortslices](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.sortslices)

```
julia> M=hcat(a,b)
4×2 Matrix{Any}:
 1  'z'
 4  'w'
 3  'x'
 2  'y'

julia> sortslices(M,dims=1,by=x->x[1])
4×2 Matrix{Any}:
 1  'z'
 2  'y'
 3  'x'
 4  'w'
```